# Why syslog stops writing?

Tags: php, rsyslog

I am trying to write data with the PHP syslog function. After writing some 500 rows rsyslogd stops writing, as if the buffer is full. It writes all data, if I make script sleep for 10 seconds after 500 rows.

How can I write all data?

Comment: rsyslog will put limits on how much data it will allow you to write, it's to stop some program from filling up the system's log directory.  You should look at configuration of rsyslogd a configuration issue. Also, this is not a programing question.

Comment: What is interesing is that one script is able to write all the messages and another just a few. I cannot understand why. What can it depend on?